# How to play different custom sounds for push notification when the app killed state in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I was able to set different push sounds for all other states except when app is in killed state. I used local notification for customising sound and other details.

But when app is in killed state app will choose the default sound the payload arrives with. My back end is very uncooperative so they won't accept a change in app setting. So I have to handle it programmatically. What is the solution?

Comment: ok, my answer was completely wrong. You can't change that, your server needs to change sound name

Comment: we can't mute the sound as well? or make a different file play?

Comment: no, app can't do anything about push, system takes care of it